# What is the difference between collect and map in the Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I was writing some code and I noticed that both map and collect do the exact same thing so I am wondering when to use what and which is more efficient.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Car("Honda", "Civic", 2023),
                new Car("Toyota", "Camry", 2023),
                new Car("BMW", "M4", 2021));
        List<String> nameList = list.stream().map(Car::brand).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> nameListCollect = list.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (lists, car) -> lists.add(car.brand()), ArrayList::addAll);
    }
}

record Car(String brand, String model, Integer year) {}
```

Comment: It would surprise me if there were any difference at all in performance, between the two lines of code that you've written.  But you tell me - which one is easier to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the first thing to note is that `map` and `collect` do *not* do the same thing. This is actually clear from your example; both of your expressions have to call `collect`, because if they didn't then you wouldn't end up with a `List`.

Instead, what you've found is that if a call to `map` is followed by something else, then you can often eliminate `map` in favor of incorporating the mapper's logic into that something else. That something else doesn't have to be a call to `collect`; it can even be another call to `map`. For example, these two expressions are equivalent:

- `stream.map(Object::toString).map(String::toLowerCase)`
- `stream.map(obj -> obj.toString().toLowerCase())`

where the former uses two separate mappers in sequence, while the latter combines them into a single expression.

The important difference is not in performance, but in readability/clarity/maintainability — and those are a human judgment that depends on context. There are no hard-and-fast rules.

In your example, I think that `.map(Car::brand).collect(Collectors.toList())` is infinitely clearer than `.collect(ArrayList::new, (lists, car) -> lists.add(car.brand()), ArrayList::addAll)`; but if you think that the latter is clearer, then I can't really point to any objective facts that prove otherwise. (I suppose you could survey the uses of `collect` on (say) GitHub to show that calls to `collect(Collectors.toList())` are far more common than calls to the three-parameter overload of `collect`; but that wouldn't really *prove* that the former is more readable, or more readable in your case.)

More broadly, I think the stream syntax works best when each step in the chain of method calls is very simple, and preferably written on a separate line. `.map(Car::brand)` and `.collect(Collectors.toList())` are both very simple and clear (if you're used to streams), whereas `.collect(ArrayList::new, (lists, car) -> lists.add(car.brand()), ArrayList::addAll)` is a large irreducible chunk that you have to think about for a while.

And when it's not possible to break up the expression into a chain of simple calls like this, I think you're actually better off going back to simple imperative code (for-loops and so on) rather than using complicated stream calls. But again, if you disagree, I can't objectively prove that this is clearer. It just *is*!